# Ruby: Disable to use link massively

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So here is the link `http://127.0.0.1:3000/zones/create_value_zone_printout?value_zone=3-0010000-001`, it can be used massively(repeated) always, i need to correct that and switch that off. What i mean by that? The link should be only working by pressing the button, not entering in browser. Maybe try to encrypt the link? Maybe someone have any idea?

```
  def create_value_zone_printout
    @service = "value_zones"

    if !public_user?
      return unless check_service_permissions
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        rep_id = Report.get_printout_file_id('VALUE_ZONE', session, {:value_zones => params[:value_zone]})
        unless rep_id.blank? or rep_id.is_a?(Array)
          return permission_denied(SilentError.new("Kļūda veidojot izdruku!", rep_id.to_s, true))
        end
        add_service_to_user_orders(nil, [params[:value_zone]], rep_id) unless public_user?

        file_data = Attachment.find_by_id(rep_id.first.keys.first)
        send_data(file_data.data_buffered, :filename => file_data.file_name)

        file_data.destroy if public_user?
      end
    end
  end

  map.resources :zones, :collection => {:create_value_zone_printout => :get}


<%= link_to 'sagatavot izdruku',  {:controller => "zones", :action => "create_value_zone_printout", :value_zone => @zone.zone_name}, :class=>"print" %>
```

P.S Only the `value_zone` id is changing in the link for each position, maybe just set only 1 request per value_zone? But its not good idea.

Ruby V.: 1.8.7

Comment: Not quite clear, but maybe you can save something into a session variable and if the variable exists, then the link redirects to somewhere. Or some javascript acting on the button.

Comment: I think you may be able to use authenticity token and the `protect_from_forgery` method. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong HTTP method.

If you want to create an non-idempotent operation you should be using one of the non-idempotent methods such as POST, PATCH, PUT or DELETE not GET.

POST, PATCH, PUT or DELETE requests are only sent by the browser by form submission*. You can't just enter the URL into the browser window as it will be sent as a GET request. The browser also warns the user if they refresh the window.

If you want to limit the operation to being performed once you would either need to save a flag on the model or a token passed through the form or some other way of saving the application state.

But maybe you should look at how to throttle the resource per user instead.

Comment: * Rails UJS actually creates a hidden form with javascript and submits it when you use `link_to "Foo", "/foo", method: "POST"`

Comment: I forgot to tell, that web-service using Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Thats pretty much irrelevant since we are talking about some pretty basic web principles here.

Comment: The web-service is not written by me, so i don't know all the stuff there. That's why im asking. It takes some time too look into the ws. Too big.